# null point exception error in hashmap

Tags: string, hashmap

I keep getting a null point exception in here and I don't know what's wrong with my code. I'm having Constructor that parses a String s like `{ x=-1 y=-2.0 z=3d }` into the internal HashMap representation of the `Vector(_hmVar2Value)`.

```
public Vector(String s) {
    String[] splitString = s.split(" ");
    for (int i=0;i<splitString.length-2;i++) {
        String[] str=splitString[i+1].split("=");
        double x = Double.parseDouble(str[1]);
        _hmVar2Value.put(str[0],x);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add a language tag

Comment: You probably forgot to initialize your hashmap: `_hmVar2Value`

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code and its works fine.
Have you initialize your hash map yet?

Try something like this

Yes you have declare it however didnt initialize it yet. Try something like this

```
public OtherClass(String s) {
            _hmVar2Value = new HashMap<String,Double>();
            String[] splitString = s.split(" ");
            for (int i=0;i<splitString.length-2;i++) {
                String[] str=splitString[i+1].split("=");
                double x = Double.parseDouble(str[1]);
                _hmVar2Value.put(str[0],x);

            }
    System.out.print(_hmVar2Value);



  }
```

Comment: private HashMap<String,Double> _hmVar2Value; although I have this and also a constructor for initially empty vector I keep getting an error

Comment: Yes you have declare it however didnt initialize it yet. I have updated my answer with some code. Hope this helps

Comment: I added the initialization. The nullpointerror is gone now but I keep getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Well without the input then I cant help you. But i guess it from oin of line String[] str=splitString[i+1].split("=");
                double x = Double.parseDouble(str[1]);
You have to debug to find out :)